# String differs after encoding and decoding

Tags: java, string, unicode, character-encoding, unicode-literals

I stumbled across weird behaviour of encoding/decoding string. Have a look at an example:

```
@Test
public void testEncoding() {
    String str = "\uDD71"; // {56689}
    byte[] utf16 = str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16); // {-2, -1, -1, -3}
    String utf16String = new String(utf16, StandardCharsets.UTF_16); // {65533}
    assertEquals(str, utf16String);
}
```

I would assume this test will pass, but it is not the case. Could someone  explain why the encoded and decoded string is not equal to the original one?

Comment: You must at least show the actual output

Comment: Which output would you like to see? the byte array? the utf16String? in what form? I think you can run this test yourself quite easily. In general the output is that those strings are different

Comment: `\uDD71` is a low surrogate. Alone it is useless and does not denote any codepoint. Therefore it is replaced with `\uFFFD`

Comment: If you prefer an exception to a replacement, avoid the String constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[U+DD71](https://codepoints.net/U+dd71) is not a valid codepoint, as U+D800..U+DFFF are reserved by Unicode so as not to cause confusion with UTF-16.  As such, these codepoints should never appear as valid character data.  From the Unicode standard:

> Isolated surrogate code points have no interpretation; consequently, no character code charts or names lists are provided for
>   this range.

This works, though:

```
@Test
public void testEncoding() {
    String str = "\u0040";
    byte[] utf16 = str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16);
    String utf16String = new String(utf16, StandardCharsets.UTF_16);
    assertEquals(str, utf16String);
}
```

So, it's not your code at fault, but that you're trying to use a codepoint that isn't valid.

Comment: I have accepted your answer, but big thank you goes to @Johannes Kuhn, who was first and helped me understand the problem.

Comment: Yes, I saw his comment after I finished my answer. He knows more about the subject than I, but this is what a Google search told me.